# PHP preg_replace - regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am still getting my head round regex and learning little by little. This one's causing me a headache. I have a string like the one below:

```
".......mapsearch"), '52.486683, -4.044363', options......"
```

I want to retrieve the 2 numbers (long & lat) from the string - I don't mind if I retrieve them together as a single string complete with the comma and space inbetween.

I know that I want to use an expression to match and ignore anything from the start up to and including the `mapsearch"), '` and the same for the end of the string to the `', options` pattern.

**UPDATE**

The string will also contain a range of other characters like { } ( ) = : / and numbers before and after the desired match..

Comment: Why not explode on `,`, then loop and check if it's a float/int to keep it?

Comment: are these the only 2 numbers that are present in the string?

Comment: Is this a line from a CSV file? You are better off using a parser for those.

Comment: @Will post a lengthier string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work, as ugly as it is:

```
/mapsearch\"\), '(-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?), (-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)', options/
```

The numbers can be negative or positive, and also it will match integers and decimal values. The pattern will return both numbers as a separate group.

Comment: A breakdown of how `(-?\d+(?:.\d+)?)` works:  the `-?` looks for an optional leading negative sign, followed by a quantity of numbers (`\d+`).  After the initial set of numbers, we want to match a decimal and a quantity of numbers (`(?:.\d+)?`), but we don't want it to be it's own capture group (`?:`).

Comment: Returns an array of 3 items - 1st of them both, 2nd and 3rd returning each variable - works nonetheless. Thanks.

Comment: preg_match (and most other regex matchers I've seen) will always return the full match as the first group. That's why there's 3 items.

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match("/'([^,]+), ([^']+)'/", $string, $matches);
echo $matches[0]; // 52.486683
echo $matches[1]; // -4.044363
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, I'd use metalfrog's solution with some changes.

If you're sure that only the string has a comma, nothing else, then explode, and either check if it's an integer/float OR if you know that it's the nth item, just get $array[$n].

Else explode and use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348502/how-to-determine-if-a-php-string-only-contains-latitude-and-longitude) (needs some editing) to determine if it is a coordinate or not.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's the only numbers in single quotes:

```
'-?\d+.\d+, -?\d+.\d+'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
(\-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\,\ \-?[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)
```

to extract

> 52.486683, -4.044363

Answer (score 0):

```
$subject = ".....mapsearch\"), '52.486683, -4.044363', options......";
$regex = '/mapsearch\"\), \'(-?[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{6}, -?[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{6})\', options/';
if (preg_match($regex, $subject, $matches)){
    print_r($matches);
```

This will give you:

```
Array
(
    [0] => mapsearch"), '52.486683, -4.044363', options
    [1] => 52.486683, -4.044363
)
```